# Docker images builds with Bazel on Apple M1

Tags: python, docker, bazel, apple-m1

I setup a new project that uses Bazel to build/package my Python applications.
The project uses `rules_python` to setup a `py_binary` rule with my source files and `rules_docker` to setup a `py_image` rule to build my image.

I am successfully able to `bazel run` the `py_binary` by itself.

But when trying to run the `py_image` rule, it succeeds with building the image, but fails to run the binary entry-point and throws the following error:

```bash
INFO: Analyzed target //demo:demo_img (110 packages loaded, 12496 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //demo:demo_img up-to-date:
  bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild-ST-9e3a93240a9e/bin/demo/demo_img-layer.tar
INFO: Elapsed time: 8.722s, Critical Path: 3.94s
INFO: 31 processes: 13 internal, 18 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 31 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 31 total actions
f83e52040704: Loading layer [==================================================>]  147.1MB/147.1MB
Loaded image ID: sha256:078152695f1056177bd21cd96171245f42f7415f5a1ff802b20fbd973eecddfd
Tagging 078152695f1056177bd21cd96171245f42f7415f5a1ff802b20fbd973eecddfd as bazel/demo:demo_img
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/demo/demo_img.binary", line 392, in <module>
    Main()
  File "/app/demo/demo_img.binary", line 382, in Main
    os.execv(args[0], args)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/app/demo/demo_img.binary.runfiles/python3_8_aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/python3'
```

Taking a look at the generated image

```bash
docker run -it --entrypoint sh bazel/demo:demo_img
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
/app/demo/demo_img.binary.runfiles/__main__ # uname -a
Linux c94f44a24832 5.10.104-linuxkit #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 17 17:05:54 UTC 2022 aarch64 Linux
```

My current setup also uses a hermetic Python interpreter following this blog post: https://thethoughtfulkoala.com/posts/2020/05/16/bazel-hermetic-python.html

I am assuming that this problem exists due to the mismatch in OS type? The Python binary is built with an interpreter using `apple/darwin` where as the image is based on `linux`?

How do I configure `py_image` to build a binary for `linux` when developing on an M1 Macbook?

---

Appendix:

The following files are part of my sample project:

`__main__.py`

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def root():
    return "OK"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`BUILD.bazel`

```
load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", "py_binary")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//python3:image.bzl", py_image = "py3_image")

py_binary(
    name = "demo_bin",
    srcs = ["__main__.py"],
    imports = [".."],
    main = "__main__.py",
    visibility = ["//:__subpackages__"],
    deps = [
        "@python_deps_flask//:pkg",
    ],
)

container_image(
    name = "py_alpine_base",
    base = "@python-alpine//image",
    symlinks = {
        "/usr/bin/python": "/usr/local/bin/python",  # To work as base for py3_image
        "/usr/bin/python3": "/usr/local/bin/python3",  # To work as base for py3_image
    },
)

py_image(
   name = "demo_img",
   srcs = ["__main__.py"],
   base = "//:py_alpine_base",
   main = "__main__.py",
   deps = [
       "@python_deps_flask//:pkg",
   ],
)
```

Where `python-alpine` is defined in `WORKSPACE`. It references an `arm64` image from dockerhub.

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl", "container_pull")

container_pull(
    name = "python-alpine",
    registry = "index.docker.io",
    repository = "arm64v8/python",
    tag = "3.8-alpine",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error usually means that instruction set of container host doesn’t match the instructions set of the container image that is attempting to initiate.

Use —platform in build command and specify linux/amd64

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am currently compiling images from the `arm64v8/python` which should match the aarch64 arch on the M1.

i've tried setting the os and cpu with the `—platform` flag, but it requires me to setup a c++ toolchain in order to do this. I am a C++ noob, is there any docs you can recommend to help set up the toolchain to cross compile?